# how to set up and play dvr streaming?

Tags: video-streaming, wowza, jwplayer7

I am using wowza. I have created a live application with dvr enabled.
Now from the encoder i start sending stream to the wowza server.
My server url is `rtmp://192.168.0.100:1935/dvr`  where `dvr` is the application name. And my stream source name is `myStream` but its not working in my wowza test player or jw player.

Comment: Are you authenticating from your encoder and/or have you disabled RTMP authentication in the Wowza Manager?

Comment: Hi @orde I have disabled the password authentication for streaming source.

Comment: I'd suggest looking the logs.  Go to the wowza root directory, and you'll see a logs directory with access and error logs.

Comment: can you provide the url which you are playing in jw player

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot DVR streaming, try the following steps:

1. Make sure that the stream is being published correctly to your "dvr" application. From the Manager UI (if you are using Wowza version 4), select your application and go into Incoming Streams. You should see "myStream" as an Active stream. Click on the stream name and make sure that there is a large enough inbound data to indicate that it is sending audio/video tracks and not just header data (which would just be around 100k).
2. If you can't see the stream as Active and with sufficient incoming data, then the problem is in the source encoder. Try a different source encoder (there's plenty of free software ones).
3. If you can see the stream correctly, test non-DVR playback on multiple formats, and test playback on a different software as well. Try VLC! This is a great troubleshooting tool to test your incoming stream as well if you have this installed on your Wowza server; if you can play your incoming stream directly, but it is not showing up as an Incoming Stream, then there's a config issue on your Wowza app.
4. The Wowza nDVR supports playback for the following HTTP formats: HLS, HDS, and Smooth. It does not support RTMP DVR playback.

To play using Adobe HDS: 
http://192.168.0.100:1935/dvr/myStream/manifest.f4m?DVR

To play using Apple HLS: 
http://192.168.0.100:1935/dvr/myStream/playlist.m3u8?DVR

To play using Microsoft Smooth Streaming: 
http://192.168.0.100:1935/dvr/myStream/manifest?DVR

5. Make sure you have the right edition of JWPlayer. AFAIK the free editions of JWPlayer does not support DVR functionality.

Comment: Thank you @Michelle-B for ur awesome answer.

Comment: I am using JW7. What should be the playback url?